# iOS: Random position of UIImage on load

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm very new to iOS so please forgive me if this is a noob question. I'm currently working on an app were an image falls from the top of the screen down to the bottom. I have got it working, however I need the image to start at the top from a random position.

Here is my complete .m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)Start {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.10)
         target: self
         selector:@selector(onTimer)
         userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void)onTimer {

    image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x+pos.x, image.center.y+pos.y);
    pos = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.17);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and my .h file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    CGPoint pos;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
    NSTimer *timer;
}

-(IBAction)Start;

@end
```

I have tried using:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

but no luck, it just falls in the same position that i placed it on the view.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's set an initial position. You want that to be called only once. So let's put it to the `Start` method.

```
- (IBAction)Start {
     //random X position
     CGFloat xPosition = arc4random_uniform((int) (self.view.bounds.size.width - image.size.width / 2.0f)) + image.size.width / 2.0f;
     //image at the top edge (y = 0.0f) of the view, x is random.
     image.center = CGPointMake(xPosition, image.size.height / 2.0f);

     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.10)
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(onTimer)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
 }
```

To make a constant fall, let's just increment a bit in every step.

```
- (void)onTimer {
   CGPoint position = image.center;
   position.y += 0.17;

   image.center = position;
}
```

To make the fall a bit more interesting, let's make the movement accelerated.

Add

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat velocity;
```

to your interface (or class extension). Add

```
self.velocity = 0.0f;
```

to the `Start` method.
And then:

```
- (void)onTimer {
   CGFloat acceleration = 50.0f; //(in pixels per second per second)
   CGFloat stepDuration = 0.1f;

   self.velocity += acceleration * stepDuration;

   CGPoint position = image.center;
   position.y += self.velocity;

   image.center = position;
}
```

You will have to experiment a bit with the value of the acceleration.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this but im getting : property 'size' is not found on object of type UIImageView with your code.

Comment: still coming up with two errors both saying the same message.

Comment: Nice answer.. (In px/second/second) in -(void)onTimer needs commenting (//) or it won't compile :)

Answer (score 0):

to randomize the start position try using

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random_uniform(320 - 100), 10, 100, 100)]; //320 is the width of an iphone screen, can change that to whatever nad -100 is for the width of the image, should have those as a variable that you can use there and as the width of the CGRect, just put it there for demo purposes
```

Comment: I added that in the viewDidLoad and it doesn't work. The warning of unused variable 'image'. Based on my code supplied, where should I add this?

Comment: ah, if you have the image already in the story board, go like `self.imageViewName.frame = CGRectMake(arc4random_uniform(320 - 100), 10, 100, 100);` in your viewDidLoad

Comment: that gives me the error: property image not found on object of type view controller when I change imageViewName to image. Which is what I specified in the .h file: IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

Comment: ah i see, you are doing things a bit weirdly with your header, when you create an outlet from your storyboard, if you control drag from the item to the .h file, it should create a @property for you, you should be using those instead. but to quick fix that dont use `self` infront of the `image` in `self.image.frame` just make it `image.frame` like how you had it in other places, but ye for correctness i would use a property, should look into that in the future

Comment: I tried that, there are no errors but it just doesnt work the image still falls down but doesnt change where it falls from. and oooooh, I'm following a tutorial and I copied the steps as per the video. so if I drag from the storyboard into the .h when it creates the @property do I just leave it as it is and not type IBOutlet UIImageView *image; in the .h ?

Comment: yeah just the property is fine, but you have to use `self.` in front of your variables, unless you `@synthesize variableName` in your .m, sounds pointless, but it creates getters and setters automatically for you which can be very useful if you want to add extra functionality when assigning objects.. but anyway, something strange is going on with your initialisation of your image then, maybe put it in `- (void) viewDidAppear`? or maybe in your start method

Comment: the guy in that tutorial was probably not using properties to try keep things simpler for new people. but im not sure why the code i suggested wouldnt work im afraid, maybe just play around a bit with it, but the `arc4random_uniform()` is the key to your success here

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but instead of the onTimer calls you could also use the animation framework. For example in your Start method:

```
-(IBAction)Start {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10. animations:^(void){
        image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x, image.center.y + 400);
    }];
}
```

This will animate the y coordinate of the center of the image 400 pixels down.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111